# Can't declare C++ vector in xcode ios project

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, vector, std

I'm trying to use a vector in a C++ class with xcode but it's giving me errors. The file has the `.mm` extension that is required for C++ files.

This is my code:

```
class Synth{

private:

    int bpm;
    std::vector<Note> notesList;

public:

};
```

It's giving me these two errors:

- error: Semantic Issue: Use of undeclared identifier 'std'
- error: Parse Issue: Expected member name or ';' after declaration specifiers

I also tried with `using namespace std;` on top but that made no difference.
Any ideas what could be causing this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you need to include the header:

```
 #include <vector>
```

Don't use `using namespace std` in a header file, rather keep your code as it is, with the explicit qualifier: `std::vector`.

Comment: That's embarrassing, I thought vector was included inside std.

Comment: @Sled `std` is a namespace. It's spread around multiple headers, not just vector.

Comment: Should I use std in the .mm file?

Comment: @Sled I'd advise you not to, unless you have a strong reason to do it. If you can, keep using directives to a minimum.

Comment: In the implementation file you case use the using namespace.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore I'm not sure we can say that std::vector is an explicit qualifier, as it could be anynamespace::std::vector. Explicit would rather be absoulte: ::std::vector

Comment: @Geoffroy you *can* use it in the header also. It's about good practice, not about whether you can or can't.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore Yes I know, I didn't say that you can't :)

Comment: @Geoffroy you're right on that one, but I honestly hope no-one would create a namespace with the name `std`.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore in the case you use multiple version of the same library, you case import the ::std namespace in a another namespace I think, though I've never tested :)